# Retirar "/" de um DateTime.ToShortDateString();

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Estou implementando um programa utilizando C# com .net 3.5

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(caminhoSalvarCobranca);
sb.Append(@"\Boleto ");
sb.Append(boleto.Sacado.Nome);
sb.Append(boleto.Boleto.DataVencimento.ToShortDateString);
```

O "`boleto.Boleto.DataVencimento.ToShortDateString`" me retorna uma string no formato de data "dd/mm/aaaa". Teria alguma função para retirar as barras ("/") e deixar somente a data (ddmmaaaa)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode fazê-lo da seguinte forma:

```
sb.Append(boleto.Boleto.DataVencimento.ToString("ddMMaaaa");
```

Desta forma, o `ToString("...")` formata a data no formato pretendido e evita manipular strings já criadas.

Nota: Para mais opções de formatação para `DateTime` consulte esta [página](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Eu gostaria de poder lhe dar um voto positivo extra pelo link ao final da resposta.

Comment: @Renan obrigado, essa página e a página para [T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) dão imenso jeito.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode estar fazendo também:

```
sb.Append(boleto.Boleto.DataVencimento.ToShortDateString().Replace("/","")); // ddMMyyyy
```

Comment: Isso é uma gambiarra. Você está intencionalmente gerando uma string com um formato que você não quer, para ajeitá-la logo em seguida. Veja a resposta do Omni.

Comment: @Renan Bom, o OP perguntou como fazer isso utilizando o `ToShortDateString`, a resposta do OMni claro é melhor, eu apenas respondi a estrita do que foi perguntado.